# pandas_ta and ta libraries gives different results for stochrsi_k and d

Tags: python-3.x, stochastic, technical-indicator, pandas-ta

I wrote a python code using :

1. yfinance
2. pandas_ta
3. ta

libraries to find stochrsi_k and stochrsi_d but the results are different with each other and from tradingview stochastic-rsi indicator(tradingview have different inputs for ohlc).
for example on ticker:'eurusd' here is one of the results for '15m' timeframe:

```
Open           1.094811e+00
High           1.094811e+00
Low            1.093853e+00
Close          1.093853e+00
Adj Close      1.093853e+00
Volume         0.000000e+00
pandas_ta k   -4.736952e-15
ta k           0.000000e+00
pandas_ta d    1.680791e+01
ta d           1.677064e-01
Name: 2023-11-27 14:00:00, dtype: float64
```

can you guide me please?
how can stochrsik give negative amount?and which library is better for technical analysis?
here are some more lines:
[Diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbWlM.png)

Comment: _"I wrote a python code"_ => show the code.